# I need to extract a part of a substring and mutliple occurences of it, if any from the html code of a website

Tags: string, python-3.x

I need to look for the symbol "&copy" in the html code of a website and extract  100 characters/n number of characters after and before the symbol respectively.

The html code might also have multiple occurrences of the symbol "&copy", in that case i need to do perform the above step for all occurrences of the symbol.

Currently i have written the code to extract for a single and the first occurrence of the symbol:

```
finalurl="https://example.com"

req=requests.get(finalurl,verify=False,headers=hdrs)

html=req.content
html=html.decode('utf-8','ignore')


if "&copy" in html:
    pos_c = html.find("&copy;")
    symbol = html[pos_c-100:pos_c+100]
    print(symbol)
```

So, if the html code of the website has "sample &copy sample 1 this is an example &copy copyright example"

I would like to get :

1.For the first occurrence of &copy : sample &copy sample 1 this

2.For the second occurrence of &copy: example &copy copyright example

Answer (score 0):

```
s='abcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc&copybebdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd'
d1=s[0:s.index('&copy')]
d2=s[s.index('&copy')+5:]
```

This is a logic to get the string before &copy and after &copy.
d1 is string before &copy and d2 is string after &copy.

Now just use a loop to count the character upto 100.

IF Multiple &copy are coming than you can use a list to capture the index of each &copy and than you can move forward using above code.

Comment: is there a way in which i dont need to use lists since i am extracting the entire html content of the websites home page